# How to automatically find a rectangle and crop in OpenCV or PIL

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, crop

I have a program that uses PIL to automatically crop a series of images to a certain area. However, when I run the program with screenshots from a different sized display, the area cropped is in the wrong place. Is there a way to use OpenCV or PIL to automatically find the rectangle that I want to crop to (for example the main viewer of a Youtube video) and crop to it, while leaving the image in color and then saving the image to a new folder?

My code for cropping images:

```py
import os, random
from PIL import Image

files = []

for x in os.listdir():
    if '.jpg' in f'{x}' or '.png' in f'{x}' or '.jpeg' in f'{x}':
        files.append(x)
    else:
        print(f'Passed by {x}! It is not an image!')
for x in files:
    y = hex(random.randint(100000,500000))
    image = Image.open(f'{x}')
    newimage = image.crop((48,367,1626,1256))
    newimage.save(f'newdir/{y}.png')
```

The example image (this works with the PIL cropper):
[image: Example image]

The image I want:
[image: the cropped image]

Another image from another computer that needs to be cropped to the same viewer:

Comment: Post an example image in which you want to crop and tell us what area you want.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: What area do you want?  Is it the white area showing the text code? If so, you can threshold the image and get the contours of the larger regions (white) and then get its bounding box. Search Google for examples of this. Use cv2.threshold() and cv2.findContours, etc.

Comment: @fmw42 The main viewer of the Youtube video. The big rectangle, just to crop out the rest of the junk from the browser and such... I've been trying with the methods you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean by the "main viewer". Can you show another version where you put a rectangle around that area in the image?

Comment: OK. That is what I thought. But what I suggested should work, if there are no other white areas that touch. Does your code not work? Can you show it?

Comment: I have no code for OpenCV... I was wondering if it could get the exact coordinates of the viewer corners and pass them to PIL.

Comment: Note that going back and forth between OpenCV and PIL will require the image to be converted each way, since the formats are different.

Comment: Is there a way to crop the same way in OpenCV?

Comment: OpenCV process that I mentioned will get the x,y,w,h. You can then pass that to PIL and convert to x1,y1,x2,y2 if that is what PIL needs.

Comment: I use Numpy to crop in my OpenCV code. I will write something for you and post as soon as I can create it.

Comment: Is there a code snippet that could use to get those values? It would really help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do that using Python/OpenCV.

Basically, threshold the image, then get contours, then get the bounding box of the largest contour and crop using the bounding box.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("screen.jpg")

# get color bounds of white region
lower =(180,180,180) # lower bound for each channel
upper = (255,255,255) # upper bound for each channel

# threshold
threshold = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get the largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get bounding box
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)
print(x,y,w,h)


# crop the image at the bounds
crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("screen_threshold.jpg", threshold)
cv2.imwrite("screen_cropped.jpg", crop)

# display it
cv2.imshow("threshold", threshold)
cv2.imshow("crop", crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Cropped Result:

[image]

Cropped (x,y,w,h):

```
48 368 1578 801
```

Comment: Is there an obvious reason why the play bar is missing? Will it crop lower?

Comment: Oh, ok! It works, thanks! Upvoting and accepting... you're amazing!

Comment: it's not working on a set of images from a friend... do you know why?

Comment: I've unaccepted the answer... I'm adding the new image (from the friend's computer) as a requirement. Sorry, but it's not working and I need it to be adaptable.

Comment: My method relies upon that area being white. You have posted an image where there is some orange colored sky. So of course it will fail. One suggestion is to threshold on black. You can do that with cv2.threshold(). Anything but black will be white. Then get the largest white region contours. Alternately, you can threshold using cv2.inRange() on black and invert, so that again the region you want is white. Finally, If it is always the same area, then just measure that manually and always crop the same region.

Comment: I would say it is a good answer and Peter Nielsen shall appreciate @fmw42 's work and accept it as the answer. If you have new inputs, then please ask a new question.